# How to calculate effective hours of employee for one day if there are multiple in and out entries in database for that employee

Tags: sql

// Below is my query that is giving result-set as shown below

```
Name, Cardno, date, Minimum In Time for day, MaximumOutTime for day

Guruprasad Marathe  14109393    03-06-2013  09:43   19:18
Guruprasad Marathe  14109393    04-06-2013  09:50   19:19
Guruprasad Marathe  14109393    05-06-2013  09:33   19:14
Guruprasad Marathe  14109393    06-06-2013  09:52   19:09
Guruprasad Marathe  14109393    07-06-2013  09:54   19:21
```

Query

```
WITH cte_tables (zcardno, zdate, zs_datetime, zchannel_no) AS 
( 
    SELECT 
       cardno, 
       DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, s_datetime), 0), 
       s_datetime, 
       [channel no] as action 
    FROM 
       transactions 
    where 
       s_datetime >= '2013-03-01' 
UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
       cardno, 
       DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, s_datetime), 0), 
       s_datetime, 
       Action 
    FROM 
       custom_transactions 
    where 
       s_datetime >= '2013-03-01'
), 
cte_minmax (acardno, adate, aMinS_datetime, aMaxS_datetime) AS 
(
    SELECT 
       zcardno, 
       zdate, 
       MIN(zs_datetime), 
       NULL 
    FROM 
       cte_tables 
    WHERE 
       zchannel_no = 2 
    GROUP BY 
       zcardno, 
       zdate 
UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
       zcardno, 
       zdate, 
       NULL, 
       MAX(zs_datetime) 
    FROM 
       cte_tables 
    WHERE 
       zchannel_no = 1 
    GROUP BY 
       zcardno, 
       zdate
) 
SELECT 
  m.name, 
  c.acardno AS cardno, 
  REPLACE(CONVERT(VarChar(50), c.adate, 103),'/','-') AS [date], 
  LEFT(CONVERT(varchar,MAX(c.aMinS_datetime),108),5) AS InTime, 
  LEFT(CONVERT(varchar,MAX(c.aMaxS_datetime),108),5) AS OutTime 
FROM cte_minmax c 
inner join master m 
  on c.acardno = m.cardno 
where acardno in ('14109393') 
  and adate between '2013-06-01' and '2013-06-08' 
GROUP BY 
  m.name, 
  c.acardno, 
  c.adate 
order by 
  c.acardno
```

Now I want a result-set which will give all In & Out timings of employee for one day and I want to calculate their difference as effective hours of employee.

2 for Out Time & 1 for In Time

Below are In & out timings for employee

```
Guruprasad Marathe  14109393    03-06-2013  2013-06-03 10:22:41.000 NULL
Guruprasad Marathe  14109393    03-06-2013  2013-06-03 09:43:39.000 NULL
Guruprasad Marathe  14109393    03-06-2013  2013-06-03 10:39:39.000 NULL
Guruprasad Marathe  14109393    03-06-2013  2013-06-03 13:49:27.000 NULL
Guruprasad Marathe  14109393    03-06-2013  2013-06-03 14:09:44.000 NULL
Guruprasad Marathe  14109393    03-06-2013  2013-06-03 15:18:34.000 NULL
Guruprasad Marathe  14109393    03-06-2013  2013-06-03 16:08:17.000 NULL
Guruprasad Marathe  14109393    03-06-2013  2013-06-03 16:44:55.000 NULL
Guruprasad Marathe  14109393    03-06-2013  NULL    2013-06-03 10:38:33.000
Guruprasad Marathe  14109393    03-06-2013  NULL    2013-06-03 10:22:13.000
Guruprasad Marathe  14109393    03-06-2013  NULL    2013-06-03 13:20:59.000
Guruprasad Marathe  14109393    03-06-2013  NULL    2013-06-03 14:09:16.000
Guruprasad Marathe  14109393    03-06-2013  NULL    2013-06-03 15:17:22.000
Guruprasad Marathe  14109393    03-06-2013  NULL    2013-06-03 16:07:51.000
Guruprasad Marathe  14109393    03-06-2013  NULL    2013-06-03 16:15:25.000
Guruprasad Marathe  14109393    03-06-2013  NULL    2013-06-03 19:18:28.000
```

Comment: That looks like SQL Server, but not 100% sure. Can you edit your question and add an appropriate tag for your database system (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc)

Comment: can you please format your query well? I tried to edit it but something is missing. Also let me know the meaning of "2 for Out Time & 1 for In Time",

Comment: @DipenduPaul : Please refresh

Comment: How would your expected result-set look like? Does the effective hours of an employee mean how much time was he inside the workplace in a given day?